# Manage versioning of custom js library

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bower

Let me first explain my current scenario. I've built a javascript library of visualisation components. The documentation is based on bootstrap's documentation style - component example runs on the respected page. There is a view for each component. The documentation project is built with ASP.NET MVC 4.

I've included all css and js in a shared view and it's shared by all the component views. So that css and js are included only on one page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/library/1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/library/1.0/css/vislib.min.css">
<script src="/library/1.0/js/vislib.min.js"></script>
<script src="/library/1.0/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/library/1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

As given above all css and js are stored in a directory library/1.0 for the version 1.0. Now when I am going to release version 1.1. With the current scenario I need to create a directory library/1.1 and put all the updated css and js in respected directory and also have to update the code as well.

This process is manual and it's tedious. I google about versioning of front-end assets and came to know about bower. I created `bower.json` as below:

```
{
  "name": "vislib",
  "description": "Example bower project for vislib",
  "version": "1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.2.0"
  },      
  "main": "vislib.min.js",
  "license": "MIT",      
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

After creating this I couldn't understand how this file works or helps me to maintain versioning of my js and css files. For jQuery and bootstrap it's fine. Bower installs components in `bower_components` and I can use it in my code as

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

How do I maintain versioning of javascript and css files via bower for each new release of a package? If possible please throw some light on how to use bower properly for maintaining version of custom js and css.

Comment: Throw everything in version control and serve the various revisions seperately? I don't think this is a use case that Bower covers.

Comment: @jgillich Thanks for the response. How does bower help me in my project for custom js and css ???

Comment: You might want to check out GulpJS or GruntJS.  they are javascript task runners that I believe have plugins that can help you.  http://gulpjs.com    http://gruntjs.com

Comment: Is it possible to register my bower package without git and use it in project ???- @Gary Storey

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.
Inside the /library create a folder called latest and put the files you want:
E.g.:

```
/library/latest/js/
/library/latest/css/
```

That way you don't have to change your existing html tags.This way a user will be sure they use the latest version of your library without manually editing their existing markup